# Find a value in a collection and assign top an variable using groovy

Tags: groovy

Hello Groovy Experts,

I am using the below command to get all the ODI Dataservers.

```
def PSchema=DServer.getPhysicalSchemas();
```

When I print the `PSchema` variable I getting the following values.

```
[oracle.odi.domain.topology.OdiPhysicalSchema ABC.X1, oracle.odi.domain.topology.OdiPhysicalSchema ABC.X2]
```

What I am trying to achieve here I will be passing `X1` or `X2` during runtime...
And then I want to validate this value with the `PSchema` result and the print the following value:

```
oracle.odi.domain.topology.OdiPhysicalSchema ABC.X2
```

I tried using the following options:

```
def PSchema44 = PSchema11.findIndexValues { it =~ /(X1)/ }
def pl=PSchema11.collect{if(it.contains ('X1)){return it}}
```

I tried for loop to check whether values are getting printed properly ..result is fine:

```
for (item in PSchema11 )
{
    println item
}
```

Comment: the proper syntax for collect should be `def pl = PSchema11.collect {it.contains('X1')}`
have you tried that?

Comment: received the following error   **groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: oracle.odi.domain.topology.OdiPhysicalSchema.contains() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [X1]
Possible solutions: toString(), toString(), toString(), notify()**

Comment: looking into the documentation, looks like `getPhysicalSchemas()` returns
 an unmodifable collection of IPhysicalSchemas

What exactly are you trying to achieve? If I understand correctly, you are passing X1 or X2 at runtime and want to select the passed value from the collection returned by `getPhysicalSchemas()` ?

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Comment: what is the X1, X2 you are passing? Is it an OdiPhysicalSchema object? actually could you add the code?

Comment: It is OdiPhysicalSchema Object...                                                   For Physical schema I do not have a method findbyname instead I have findbyid which I do not want to use ...and its impossible to remember the id since I am passing the value in the runtime....                                                           def Phys= 'X1'
def Phys1 = "oracle.odi.domain.topology.OdiPhysicalSchema ${Phys}"
String[] PSchema=DServer.getPhysicalSchemas(); /* I tried storing in an array first*/
then tried with the below command 
def PSchema=DServer.getPhysicalSchemas();

Comment: please surround code in these quotes ` for readability

Comment: sorry about  that !

Comment: Ive no idea why youre doing this `def Phys1 = "oracle.odi.domain.topology.OdiPhysicalSchema ${Phys}"`, also `def Phys= 'X1'` is a String, not a OdiPhysicalSchema. Looking at the api, ill try to write up an answer and see if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming 'X1' and 'X2' are the names for the physical schemas, you should be able to do something like this:

```
def phys = "X1"
def pSchemas = dServer.getPhysicalSchemas()
def schema = pSchemas.find{it.schemaName == phys}
```

also I guess you are new to Groovy, I suggest you read up on syntax and naming conventions. For example, variable names should always start with a lower case letter

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Can you please suggestion standard naming convention if you have any !

Comment: For some groovy style conventions, see http://groovy-lang.org/style-guide.html . As for naming conventions, pretty much the same as Java naming conventions, see http://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions